# Filter MYsql Data for static page report

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a Report Page that will give results from database about each marketer if you will. I currently trying to make the report page dynamic. I'm want to have a drop-down-box for each marketer.

So looking for way to have a combo- box with each marketer that i can click on to show their reports. I know the value will = the MySQL expression just not sure how to make this happen. Currently they all have their own pages and and links to those pages. which becomes a hassle to edit all current pages when needing to add something.

current database table as follows.

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
id  int(10) No       
timestamp   timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
marketer    varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
name    varchar(100)    Yes     NULL     
type    varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
phone   varchar(12) Yes     NULL     
email   varchar(50) Yes     NULL     
fax varchar(12) Yes     NULL     
description varchar(500)    Yes     NULL     
locality    varchar(35) Yes     NULL     
state   varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
zip varchar(5)  Yes     NULL     
latlng  varchar(256)    Yes     NULL     
facility    varchar(100)    Yes     NULL     
marketer_id
```

My Query for individual marketer.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer = 'Scott' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
```

results fetched

```
   `<div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Todays' Marketing Leads<?php echo $row_User['FirstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_User['LastName']; ?>.</h1>
    <hr>
    <table border="1">

<?php echo $alertMessage; ?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Marketer</th>
        <th>Facility</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Location Mapped</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {

        // we have data!
        // output the data

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td><td>" . $row['marketer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['facility'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['locality'] . "</td><td>" . $row['state'] . "</td><td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td><td>" . $row['latlng'] . "</td>";



            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else { // if no entries
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>There are no current leads today!</div>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>


</table>`
```

[Report HTML code](//imgur.com/nGgaCPH)

[Html Report dynamic](//imgur.com/ZnRJ8YQ)

Comment: If you really want help, provide the PHP code that makes one of the marketer's report instead of the useless output image.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect information needed. I provided the php code as well. Thanks @JuliePelletier

Answer (score 1):

You can add a small form to your page with a select-menu where you can choose your marketeer. Something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="marketeers">
        <option value="Scott">Scott</option>
        <option value="marketeer2">marketeer 2</option>
        <option value="marketeer3">marketeer 3</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When submitting this form it will send the information to itself and reload the page.

Then read the send information in your php-script and add it to your query:

```
$marketeer = $_POST['marketeers'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer = '".$marketeer."' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";
```

Hope it helps.